# segmentation fault in the menu when selecting options?

Tags: c

In the menu part of the checking syntax program, I have experienced segmentation error, I have 3 variables:

```
int c, Option;
char menu[MAXCHAR];
```

They are used in the menu, with c being used in the `entertext(c)` part to check syntax. The menu is used as a selection to enable the program to repeat the display of the menu as long as the user doesn't want the program to exit:

```c
printf("------------MENU------------\n");
printf("Option 1: Enter text.\n");
scanf("%d\n", Option);
if (Option == 1){
    entertext(c);
}else{
    printf("Invalid Option");
}

printf("Would you like to quit the program? \n");
scanf("%s", menu);

while (menu == "no" || menu == "No" || menu == "NO"){
    printf("------------MENU------------\n");
    printf("Option 1: Enter text.\n");
    scanf("%d\n", Option);
    if (Option == 1){
        entertext(c);
    }else{
        printf("Invalid Option");
    }

    printf("Would you like to quit the program? \n");
    scanf("%s", menu);

    brace = bracket = parenthesis = 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d\n", Option);` should be `scanf("%d\n", &Option);`

Comment: When I entered the option, the selection statement : `if (Option == 1){printf("test\n"); entertext(c); }else{ printf("Invalid Option.\n"); }`, I have typed test print statements under `(Option == 1)` but they don't print for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `scanf` to read an integer, you need to give the *address* of the target variable as the argument. So, instead of `scanf("%d\n", Option);` you should have `scanf("%d\n", &Option);` (twice, in your code).

(In the case of reading the `menu` variable, the `&` is not needed as `menu` is an array which, as a function call parameter, will implicitly *decay* to a pointer.)

Also, you can't compare `C` strings using the `==` operator - you will need to use the `strcmp` function. So, instead of:

```c
while (menu == "no" || menu == "No" || menu == "NO"){
```

use:

```c
while (!strcmp(menu,"no") || !strcmp(menu,"No") || !strcmp(menu,"NO")){
```

(The `!` checks that the return value is `zero` - which it will be if the strings are the same.)

Comment: so, if `menu` is an array of chars, use of `==` is wrong.